# Modeless UserForm won't allow user to change windows

Tags: vba, userform, modeless

I have a script which will cycle through 500+ files and make minor edits using a find and replace procedure.  If the string cannot be found, however, I'd like the code to open a `Modeless UserForm` which will allow for manual editing.  I would have like to execute a different subroutine after opening the `UserForm`, but because I am using a `For Each` loop, I cannot exit the routine and then return.

The script works, except when the `Save_User` is opened, it behaves as if it were `Modal`.  There are two windows which will be open, but I can select neither of them, and the preview of each window is white in the taskbar.  Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

```
Option Explicit
Public WB As Workbook, Template As Workbook
Public FindSelection As Range, ReplaceSelection As Range, FirstRow As Range, SecondRow As Range, StaticRange() As String
Public Target As Range, LastRow As Integer
Public FindRange As String, ReplaceRange As String, FindText As String, ReplaceText As String
Public Count As Integer, Updated As Integer
Public Const FilePath = "C:\GenericPath"

Public Sub AddApplicable()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim File As Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(FilePath)

Count = 0
Updated = 0

For Each File In Folder.Files
    If File.Type Like "Microsoft Excel*" Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(File.Path)

        Set FindSelection = WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("K17:W40")
        Set ReplaceSelection = WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("X17:AJ40")

        LastRow = WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("K40:W40").End(xlUp).Row

        Set Target = FindSelection.Find(FindText, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Target Is Nothing Then
            If LastRow = 39 Then

                Save_User.Show vbModeless
                While Save_User.Visible
                    DoEvents
                Wend

                GoTo NextAdd

            Else
                If LastRow Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("K" & LastRow + 1, "W" & LastRow + 1) = FindText
                    WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("X" & LastRow + 1, "AJ" & LastRow + 1) = _
                    Add_User.txtFirst.Value
                    WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("X" & LastRow + 2, "AJ" & LastRow + 2) = _
                    Add_User.txtSecond.Value

                Else
                    WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("K" & LastRow + 2, "W" & LastRow + 2) = FindText
                    WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("X" & LastRow + 2, "AJ" & LastRow + 2) = _
                    Add_User.txtFirst.Value
                    WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("X" & LastRow + 3, "AJ" & LastRow + 3) = _
                    Add_User.txtSecond.Value

                End If

                WB.Close True
                Updated = Updated + 1

            End If

        Else

            Set FirstRow = WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("X" & Target.Row, "AJ" & Target.Row)
            Set SecondRow = WB.Worksheets("Repair Instruction").Range("X" & Target.Row + 1, "AJ" & Target.Row + 1)
            FirstRow.Value = Add_User.txtFirst.Value
            SecondRow.Value = Add_User.txtSecond.Value
            WB.Close True

        End If

    End If

NextAdd:
    Count = Count + 1
    Next File

    Unload Applicable_User
    Unload Add_User
    Unload Ref_User
    Unload Replace_User

MsgBox (Updated & " of " & Count & " files updated.")

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

David, thank you!  I wouldn't have even considered that as the reason, but I'm grateful that it is relatively simple!  I am not aware of any other functions that would hide the cycling Excel files, so I edited the `If` statement with the `Save_User` to be:

```
 If LastRow = 39 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            WB.Activate
            Save_User.Show vbModeless
            While Save_User.Visible
                DoEvents
            Wend

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            GoTo NextAdd
 ...
 End If
```

The cycling Excel windows now appear for editing, but I can't actually make any changes (my cursor is now a crosshair, and I can select cells but not change their values).  None of the Workbooks should be protected, so is there something that I'm missing?  Or perhaps a better way to hide the activity in the background (because I don't want 500+ files to appear and disappear)?

Comment: Are you able to edit via the Formula bar?

Comment: @DavidZemens I can delete the value in the Formula bar, and if I press the `Enter` key it acts as if `Alt+Enter` would normally.  But I can't type anything else in the Formula Bar.

Comment: I think this should be a new question (you should resist the urge to hijack an existing question with a series of follow-up questions/problems...)

Comment: @DavidZemens thank you for the suggestion.  Before I do that, should I try a different method/function rather than `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to hide the background work?  I just want to ensure I haven't made another simple mistake before I post a new question.

Comment: You could conceivably open each file in a separate instance of Excel, and make that instance's `.Visible = False`, only making it visible if needed, but I am not sure whether that would be better or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your culprit:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

This prevents user input.